# numpy array.shape behaviour

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

For following:

```
d = np.array([[0,1,4,3,2],[10,18,4,7,5]])
print(d.shape)
```

Output is:

> (2, 5)

It is expected.

But, for this(difference in number of elements in individual rows):

```
d = np.array([[0,1,4,3,2],[10,18,4,7]])
print(d.shape)
```

Output is:

> (2,)

How to explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: It parses it as an array of two *objects*: two lists.

Numpy is used to process "rectangular" data. In case you pass it non-rectangular data, the `np.array(..)` function will fallback on considering it a list of *objects*.

Indeed, take a look at the `dtype` of the array here:

```
>>> d
array([list([0, 1, 4, 3, 2]), list([10, 18, 4, 7])], dtype=object)
```

It is an one-dimensional `array` that contains *two items* two lists. These lists are simply objects.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Btw, any good numpy resource for python beginners?

Comment: There's a lot of `numpy` documentation. But the problem with your example is that it's a kind of error, trying to make a 2d array from lists that differ in size.  `np.array` normally makes a multidimensional numeric array.  Making the 1d object dtype array is a fall-back alternative.  It get's a lot of attention in SO questions, not so much in the formal documentation or tutorials.